# SVN tagging a release in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, svn

I'm fairly new to Jenkins Pipeline groovy scripts but I have written a script which performs an SVN Checkout, NuGet Restore, etc and eventually copying an msi file to the server.  After successfully packaging the .msi file I would like to tag the source in SVN but I'm struggling to find a method of doing this.

The svn check out is performed as follows:

```
def svn = checkout scm
```

I was sort of hoping I could just to the following:

```
svn = copy scm "svn://svn/MyPath/MyApp/tag/${versionNumber}" -m "V${versionNumber}"
```

I could obviously use the bat command and specify the full svn command but then I'd have to enter the Jenkins credentials into the groovy script which is not ideal.

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are tied to Subversion you could extract bits of code from [this](http://www.level533.com/2013/01/tagging-a-jenkins-build-in-subversion) post, but I would HIGHLY recommend, if you can, to migrate your code to Git as the tooling support in Git is so much better and where the world has already gone.

In Git this is all I have to do tag a branch as part of my Jenkins multibranch pipeline:

```
success {
    script {
        if( "${env.BRANCH_NAME}" == "develop" ) {
            bat "git tag ${JOB_NAME}_${BUILD_NUMBER}"
            bat "git push ${env.REPO} --tags"
        }
    }
}
```

`${env.REPO}` is my clone URL.

SO much easier.

Comment: Thank you, I believe I can use the code from your link to do what I need.  I am constantly requesting that we move to Git but it is yet to happen.

Comment: Thanks Jason, appreciate if you could up vote if my answer has helped

Comment: Sorry, I tried this yesterday but as my reputation is less than 15 it says it's recorded but not publicly displayed.  Hopefully when I hit 15 it will get shown automatically.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I'm sure it will all come out in the wash

Comment: How you can provide credentials on a "safe" way with this approach?

Comment: @Domin, what credentials?

Comment: Sorry @AndrewGray, I just notice your code was for Git.
I was looking for something for SVN and I had some doubts about how I could provide credentials (user & password) to SVN.